# Cannot see ellipses in a list

Tags: list

I have a list in which it seems like I cannot click the three dots I need to click to see the version history of that elements (or any of the other options those three dots gives me access to).

How can I get those back?

I am using Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably removed the Title field from the view you're currently using. Go to List Settings and check if you can add it again. Look for "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" and tick the check box in the Display column.